# vsftpd - Allow access certain user only from certain IP range

Tags: ftp, centos6, vsftpd

I am using CentOS 6 (64bit) and have VSFTPD installed.

I have two different users for vsftpd: `privateuser` and `publicuser`.

I need to configure that only `privateuser` can login to the ftp server from the local IP range (192.168.2/24) and `publicuser` can login from both the local range and another public range (example 192.168.2/24 and 180.150/16).

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly with vsftpd. You may get some mileage with [pam_access](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_access) e.g.

edit /etc/pam.d/vsftpd and add the line

```
account    required    pam_access.so
```

to the beginning of the file, then edit /etc/security/access.conf and add the lines

```
- : privateuser : ALL EXCEPT 192.168.2.0/24
- : publicuser : ALL EXCEPT 192.168.2.0/24 180.150.0.0/16
```

which I think does what you want.

You may find it easier to switch to something like [proftpd](http://proftpd.open-source-solution.org/docs/) which has a richer set of access controls.